# MLE for bivariate distribution

Tags: r, estimation, maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, python

I am trying to estimate parameters defining the rate of a Poisson bivariate distributions. (...following Maher's 1982 paper "Modelling association football scores"). Basically I have random variables $Z_{i,j} = X_{i,j}\cdot Y_{i,j}$ (here the $X_{i,j}$ and the $Y_{i,j}$ are independent and follow Poisson distributions with rates $\alpha_i\cdot \beta_j$ and $\alpha_j\cdot \beta_i\cdot\rho$ respectively, and $\alpha_i,\beta_j$ and $\rho$ are positive numbers for $1\le i,j \le N$. I have $M$ samples $(x,y)$.

Depending on the case, $N$ is under one hundred, and $M$ in the thousands.

So what is the best approach here to estimate the parameters? I haven't found a solver for the bivariate case. I'd need to optimize functions of the sort
$$
{\mathcal L}(x_i,y_j; \alpha_i,\beta_j:1\le i,j\le N) =\sum_{k=1}^M -(\alpha_{i_k}\beta_{j_k}) + x_k\log(\alpha_{i_k}\beta_{j_k}) - (\alpha_{j_k}\beta_{i_k}\rho)+y_k\log(\alpha_{i_k}\beta_{j_k})
$$
where the index $k$ is an ordering of the sample and, e.g., the $k$-th sample is drawn from the distribution $P(\alpha_{i_k}\beta_{j_k})P(\alpha_{j_k}\beta_{i_k}\rho)$.

Alternatively, I considered this as a univariate problem, first estimating the $\alpha$s, then the $\beta$s. I have successfully done this using scipy.optimize: basically

1. I start with the initial guesses $\hat\alpha_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{1\le i,j\le N,i\neq j} x_{i,j}}} \sum_{j\neq i}x_{i,j}$ and $\hat\beta_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{1\le i,j\le N,i\neq j} x_{i,j}}} \sum_{j\neq i}x_{i,j}$ suggested by Maher,
2. I estimate the $\alpha_i$s using Nelder-Mead optimization method from scipy.optimize with function 
   $$
   {\mathcal L}_\alpha(\alpha_i;x_k,\beta_j:1\le i,j\le N,1\le k\le M) =\sum_{k=1}^M -(\alpha_{i_k}\beta_{j_k}) + x_k\log(\alpha_{i_k}\beta_{j_k})
   $$ 
   I update the initial guess $\hat \alpha_i$s with the newfound estimation, and next I estimate the $\beta_j$s.
3. I loop over the above procedure.
4. I do the same with the $\gamma_i$ and $\delta_j$.

As I write this, I am running experiments checking the prediction's accuracy from historical data. Results tend to be a little over %50.